# SQL using BULK INSERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know to do a bulk insert I can do something like:

```
    BULK INSERT tblName FROM 'c:\bulktext.text' With (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',')
```

I only have 4 columns in in bulktext.text but tblName has 20 columns. How do I insert into only those 5  columns into tblName.

Is there a way to say which columns should be inserted in the BULK statement

Comment: Use a format file :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179250.aspx or dump whole data in some temporary or staging table and then copy it into main table.

Comment: I'm confused - does your file have more columns than the table or less? And is it 4, 5, 20?

Answer (score 4):

While you can use a format file to handle this with `BULK INSERT`, I find this method extremely cumbersome and error-prone. YMMV. Other ideas:

1. insert into a staging table, and only insert the desired columns into the destination
2. use another method like OPENROWSET(BULK or SSIS or BCP
3. write a pre-parser that will take the files and output new files with only the relevant columns
4. change whatever is producing these files to output additional files with only the relevant columns

In a previous project, we used (3) to our great advantage - we were able to re-write files without bothering SQL with useless data, and reject invalid data far earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: Is this correct ? [Wouldn't this do what the OP wants ?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191175(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @bhs:- Yes this is correct. This is just another idea of doing what OP wants!!! I have shared the idea which you mentioned!!! :)

Comment: This answer has been edited from originally saying that it was not possible to use a format file.

Comment: @bhs so an answer that has been updated and is now correct should be down-voted? Nice community spirit. Usually you down-vote answers that are wrong and remove your down-vote when they've been corrected, not the other way around. Let me go find some of your answers that have been edited...

Comment: Your answer was originally wrong though ? Downvote removed though as I guess you're right overall.

Comment: @bhs None of us is perfect. I was over-stating reality trumped up by my opinion - *I* would never use `BULK INSERT` to do that, so I should have said *shouldn't* instead of *can't*. You should learn to judge the answer *now*, not how it got there. Unless every answer you write is perfect on the first try? Would you like people to down-vote your old answers not based on their current form but based on the first edit?

Comment: Point taken. But I was only responding really to the comment from @RahulTripathi. Reading the comments now makes it look like I'm questioning your latest answer and not the original because you have changed the tone of your answer.

Comment: @bhs:- Also I already said it is just another idea of doing things what OP wants!!! :)

Comment: @bhs is that sarcasm? Is this really the fight you want to pick?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Relax please. And what exactly do you mean by that ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore a field while doing bulk insert , instead try to Load all 20 column and drop the colum which you dont want

You can check out [Use a Format File to Skip a Table Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms179250.aspx)

Also check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms178129.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a format file

[Check out this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190396%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Microsoft's recommended method of a specially crafted format file, described in [BOL here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx)
If this is an issue, you'd want to use @Aaron Bertrand's methods above.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, Creating a View that maps only those four columns and then `BULK INSERT`ing to *that* works also, and it's a lot easier than a Format File.

But @AaronBertand's suggestion of using a dedicated staging table is really a much better idea (that's how most DBAs usually do it).